# New BGE mouse look actuator causing camera shake

Tags: game-engine, armature, camera, constraints, parent

Bone-parenting the camera to an armature being rotated by a control object with the “mouse look” actuator on it causes the parented mesh shake all over the place, at least in my experience, I'm on 2.76.

The end result in my game is violently quivering player arms ‘holding’ a stationary object/weapon. I’ve also had the object itself do this (with the arms remaining still) under different parenting which I assume is because only siblings of the camera are affected (in my rig the arms, torso and head move together with the camera parented to the head independent of the lower body, this is a basic FPS setup)

[I’ve greatly simplified my character setup to make it easier to exactly what’s going on clearly.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq6up55929px3b8/bone%20parented%20camera%20anomaly.blend?dl=0) The scene is as follows:

- A single bone representing the body, “Copy Rotation”-constrained to a
  control object
- A single bone representing the hand/arm bone-parented to the body
- A cube weight-parented to the hand bone representing the character
  mesh (so you can see the effect)
- A single vertex control object with “mouse look” logic (to which the
  body is constrained to in order to rotate)
- A camera parented to the upper body bone (the POV camera)

Is this a bug in Blender? Are you really unable to attach objects to a mouse actuator-controlled character armature without glitchiness? Or am I missing something?